# My Project Admin is not working on my Localhost for PHP

Tags: php, login-script

I am working on a osCommerce project, which is accessible on the main server, but when i try to access the admin portion of the project on my LOCALHOST the login page do accepts my login, ideally it should accept my login and redirect me to index,php..
below is the login script i am using..

```
<?php
  require('includes/application_top.php');

  if ($session_started == false) {
  echo 'session not started';
  }

  $error = false;
  if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['action']) && ($HTTP_GET_VARS['action'] == 'process')) {
    $email_address = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['email_address']);
    $password = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['password']);

// Check if email exists
    $check_admin_query = tep_db_query("select admin_id as login_id, admin_groups_id as login_groups_id, admin_firstname as login_firstname, admin_email_address as login_email_address, admin_password as login_password, admin_modified as login_modified, admin_logdate as login_logdate, admin_lognum as login_lognum from " . TABLE_ADMIN . " where admin_email_address = '" . tep_db_input($email_address) . "'");
    if (!tep_db_num_rows($check_admin_query)) {
      $HTTP_GET_VARS['login'] = 'fail';
    } else {
      $check_admin = tep_db_fetch_array($check_admin_query);

      //BOF code for cPanel installer - convert password to cre hash
      $check_password = $check_admin['login_password'];
      if (substr($check_password, 0, 8) == '_cPanel_'){
        $check_password = substr($check_password, 8);
        $password_hash = tep_encrypt_password($check_password);
        tep_db_query("UPDATE " . TABLE_ADMIN . " SET admin_password = '" . $password_hash . "'");
        $check_admin_query = tep_db_query("select admin_id as login_id, admin_groups_id as login_groups_id, admin_firstname as login_firstname, admin_email_address as login_email_address, admin_password as login_password, admin_modified as login_modified, admin_logdate as login_logdate, admin_lognum as login_lognum from " . TABLE_ADMIN . " where admin_email_address = '" . tep_db_input($email_address) . "'");
        $check_admin = tep_db_fetch_array($check_admin_query);
      }
      //EOF code for cPanel installer - convert password to cre hash

      // Check that password is good
      if (!tep_validate_password($password, $check_admin['login_password'])) {
        $HTTP_GET_VARS['login'] = 'fail';
      } else {
        if (tep_session_is_registered('password_forgotten')) {
          tep_session_unregister('password_forgotten');
        }

        $login_id = $check_admin['login_id'];
        $login_groups_id = $check_admin[login_groups_id];
        $login_firstname = $check_admin['login_firstname'];
        $login_email_address = $check_admin['login_email_address'];
        $login_logdate = $check_admin['login_logdate'];
        $login_lognum = $check_admin['login_lognum'];
        $login_modified = $check_admin['login_modified'];

        tep_session_register('login_id');
        tep_session_register('login_groups_id');
        tep_session_register('login_firstname');

        //$date_now = date('Ymd');
        tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_ADMIN . " set admin_logdate = now(), admin_lognum = admin_lognum+1 where admin_id = '" . $login_id . "'");

        if (($login_lognum == 0) || !($login_logdate) || ($login_email_address == 'admin@localhost') || ($login_modified == '0000-00-00 00:00:00')) {
          tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_ADMIN_ACCOUNT, '', 'SSL'));
        } else {
          tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, '', 'SSL'));
        }

      }
    }
  }

  require(DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $language . '/' . FILENAME_LOGIN);
  include('includes/functions/rss2html.php');
?>
```

I tried tracking the issue, whenever I login with correct email and password it doesnt give me the "**$HTTP_GET_VARS['action']**"

Could someone guide me whats going wrong here?

> **ACCORDING TO THE INITIAL REPLIES**

i have register_long_arrays enabled in my localhost and it is working very well in case of wrong input of email address and password..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables such as `HTTP_GET_VARS` are called *long-arrays*, and are deprecated -- and can be disabled.

See the **[`register_long_arrays`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays)** directive, about this : maybe it's disabled on your server ?

Instead of `$HTTP_GET_VARS`, you should be using the `$_GET` super-global array.

For a couple of references, see :

- [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)
- [Predefined Variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php)

Note : OS-commerce is a quite old piece of software, and was developped before long-arrays were deprecated -- which is probably why they are used... and why it is possible to enable the `register_long_arrays` directive in PHP's configuration.

Of course, this is not recommended for new software... But if you have to work with that... it might be easier than replacing every instance of `$HTTP_GET_VARS`.

Comment: They are enabled in my localhost

Answer (score 0):

$HTTP_GET_VARS is old and deprecated, use $_GET instead. Same applies to other superglobals as well: $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER, $_COOKIES, $_FILES, etc.

Comment: I know about it, i am using osCommersce v2 every where these Global variables are prominent, this is not the problem with my code which unables the access

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_GET['action']` instead of $`HTTP_GET_VARS['action']`. I suggest you entirely replace `$HTTP_GET_VARS` with `$_GET`.

> As of PHP 5.0.0, the long PHP
>   predefined variable arrays may be
>   disabled with the register_long_arrays
>   directive.

Comment: Just to be sure, try to paste $HTTP_GET_VARS = $_GET; on top of your script.

Comment: Is there any error report at all? Try using error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.0.3 long predefined arrays such `HTTP_GET_VARS` got disabled by default. Use this instead:

```
$_GET['action'];
```

Comment: but they are active in my insertion of wrong email address and password, hence it proves that they are working with my code